# How scala compiler invoking abstract method from super class?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala world and bit confused with OOPS concept . Here is my code snippet.

```
abstract class Element {
  def contents: Array[String]
  val lenth = contents.size
  val maxLength = contents.map(_.size).max
}
class ArrayElement(var contents: Array[String]) extends Element
```

From my understanding Scala compiler will generate contents , contents_= method for us. hence we can avoid to define  def contents abstract method in base class. is it my understanding correct ? if it yes

```
val names = Array("welcome", "apple", "Test")
    val names1 = Array("apple", "Test")
    var t = new ArrayElement(names);
    println(t.contents.mkString(",")) //Op : welcome,apple,Test
    t.contents = names1 // because of var
```

#1     println(t.contents.mkString(",")) // op : apple,Test
   #2     println(t.lenth) // here i am getting 3 (length of names) . but i am expecting 2 . Why ?
    #3    println(t.maxLength) // same names reference here . Why ?

'#1 is giving updated names list. But #2 and #3 is giving old name references. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `lenth` and `maxLength` are states of the object `ArrayElement` and it gets updated just once during the initialization of 
`ArrayElement` class. After you chnaged `contents`,  both lenth and maxLength are not updated with `names1`.

If you are looking for updated  `lenth` and `maxLength`.

```
abstract class Element {
  def contents: Array[String]

  //  val lenth = contents.size
  //  val maxLength = contents.map(_.size).max

  def lenth = contents.size
  def maxLength = contents.map(_.size).max

}
```

Of course , you can achieve this in different ways.

Comment: you can also apply "uniform access principle" to make the solution even more elegant.

Comment: I would suggest two books . Programming Scala 2nd edition . another books is called Programming in Scala ( written by Scala creator)..

Comment: Both are same books. only version is differing

Answer (score 3):

If you decompile **Element** class you will find something similar to this:

```
public abstract class Element {
  private final int lenth =  // call contents()
  private final int maxLength = // call contents()

  public abstract String[] contents();

  public int lenth() {
    return this.lenth;
  }

  public int maxLength() {
    return this.maxLength;
  }
}
```

So **lenth** and **maxLength** fields are initialized once during object creation stage and never change.

And when you decompile ArrayElement class there will be something like this:

```
public class ArrayElemen extends Element {

  private String[] contents;

  @Override
  public String[] contents() {
      return this.contents;
  }

  //...
}
```

So when you call **t.contents** it will be translated to **t.contents()** returning your changed value.